# Move a cursor inside a window - ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I made a window using ncurse and I am trying to be able to move my cursor using arrow keys inside my window and only inside it. For what I understood I have to use `wmove()` but apparently I didn't get how to use it.

Here's some code snippets to let you know what I did:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  WINDOW *my_win;
  int startx, starty, width, height;
  int ch;
  int x = 50;
  int y = 5;

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  noecho();

  height = 10;
  width = 100;
  starty = (LINES - height) / 2;
  startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
  printw("Press F1 to exit");
  refresh();
  my_win = create_newwin(25, 50, y, x);
  wmove(my_win, y, x);

  while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {
      if ((ch = getch()) == KEY_RIGHT)
        wmove(my_win, y++, x++);
      refresh();
  }

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

```c
WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{
  WINDOW *local_win;

  local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
  box(local_win, 0, 0);
  wrefresh(local_win);

  return (local_win);
}
```

Comment: Not too familiar with ncurses, but should `create_newwin(25, 50, y, x)` instead be `create_newwin(starty, startx, height, width)`? Then it looks like you're putting the cursor in the lower-right corner with `wmove(my_win, y, x)`, and when `KEY_RIGHT` is pressed, attempting to move it down and to the right, when you're already as far as you can go in that direction.

Comment: @Steve I just edited my question to let you see my create_newwin. According to my function, create_newwin(25, 50, y, x) seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I just played a little with your code.

I think the main Problem is that you did `refresh()` the whole screen, when refreshing the window `wrefresh (my_win)` would have been enough.

Second Problem: you did wait for a keystrke twice:
 1. in the `while` loop
 2. in the `if` statement.

`getch()`in the while loop is enough. We can use ch inside the loop to detect what key has been pressed.

I would do a `switch` instead of the`if`selection:

```
  while((ch = getch()) != 'q')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
          case KEY_LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
          case KEY_RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
          case KEY_UP:
            y--;
            break;
          case KEY_DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        }

        wmove(my_win, y, x);
        wrefresh(my_win);
    }
```

I also removed some unnessacery declarations.

Here's what I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{
  WINDOW *local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
  box(local_win, 0, 0);
  wrefresh(local_win);

  return (local_win);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  WINDOW *my_win;

  int ch;
  int x = 2;
  int y = 2;

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  noecho();

  printw("Press q to exit");
  refresh();
  my_win = create_newwin(10, 20, y, x);
  wmove(my_win, y, x);
  wrefresh(my_win);

  while((ch = getch()) != 'q')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
          case KEY_LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
          case KEY_RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
          case KEY_UP:
            y--;
            break;
          case KEY_DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        }

        wmove(my_win, y, x);
        wrefresh(my_win);
    }

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

If x or y get bigger or smaller than the window size, the cursor isn't moving, but values are changeing nonetheless. So be sure that you only allow decrease or increase of x and y when the value is inside window size!

Hint:

```
case KEY_LEFT:
   if (x>0) { x--; }
   break;
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, a better solution would be to use `wgetch` for the `my_win` window, and eliminate most of the calls to `refresh` and `wrefresh`.  `wgetch` (`getch`) does a refresh on the window in which it is reading.  The changes to Zehetner's example would be like this:

```
--- foo3.c.orig 2015-04-02 19:53:18.000000000 -0400
+++ foo3.c      2015-04-02 19:56:31.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,11 +1,12 @@
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ncurses.h>

+static
 WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
 {
   WINDOW *local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
   box(local_win, 0, 0);
-  wrefresh(local_win);
+  keypad(local_win, TRUE);

   return (local_win);
 }
@@ -27,9 +28,8 @@
   refresh();
   my_win = create_newwin(10, 20, y, x);
   wmove(my_win, y, x);
-  wrefresh(my_win);

-  while((ch = getch()) != 'q')
+  while((ch = wgetch(my_win)) != 'q')
     {
         switch (ch)
         {
@@ -45,10 +45,12 @@
           case KEY_DOWN:
             y++;
             break;
+          default:
+            beep();
+            break;
         }

         wmove(my_win, y, x);
-        wrefresh(my_win);
     }

    endwin();
```

or (resulting program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

static
WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{
  WINDOW *local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
  box(local_win, 0, 0);
  keypad(local_win, TRUE);

  return (local_win);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  WINDOW *my_win;

  int ch;
  int x = 2;
  int y = 2;

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  noecho();

  printw("Press q to exit");
  refresh();
  my_win = create_newwin(10, 20, y, x);
  wmove(my_win, y, x);

  while((ch = wgetch(my_win)) != 'q')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
          case KEY_LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
          case KEY_RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
          case KEY_UP:
            y--;
            break;
          case KEY_DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
          default:
            beep();
            break;
        }

        wmove(my_win, y, x);
    }

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have loved if details to `wmove` were actually addressed here. This answer completely takes away from OP's question, and that includes people who are searching about using wmove to put the cursor inside of a particular window.